# What causes "Open Card in Trello" in my Gmail messages?

Tags: gmail, trello

I receive Trello updates in Gmail. Recently, Gmail adds an <kbd>Open Card in Trello</kbd> button in the conversations list:

[image: my Gmail inbox]

How does that work? Is it triggered by a URL in the message?

Is this functionality unique to Trello?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it's not unique to Trello. It's a feature that Gmail has that certain apps have taken advantage of to tell Gmail things about it to give you a shortcut without having to open the message.

For instance, Google Calendar invitations have an "RSVP" button in the conversation subject. If Gmail recognizes that there's a package tracking number in the message, it adds a "Track" button. An Open Table reservation confirmation results in a "View reservation" button.

They're called "**Quick Actions**". The apps generating the message need to format the message in a particular way.

- [Official Google Accouncement](https://gmail.googleblog.com/2013/05/take-action-right-from-inbox.html)
- [Techcrunch: Gmail’s “Quick Action” Buttons Now Support One-Click Access To Google Offers, Seamless, OpenTable, Dropbox & More](https://techcrunch.com/2013/11/11/gmails-quick-action-buttons-now-support-one-click-access-to-google-offers-seamless-opentable-dropbox-more/)
- [Litmus: Quick Actions Allow Gmail Users to Convert Before Opening](https://litmus.com/blog/quick-actions-allow-gmail-users-to-convert-before-opening)